# Unable to parse range in google sheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

```
const { sheets } = await authentication()

const response =
    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId:
            "13BMKBHCQ94tgv9koMkzH1bvgPZhaz0yZW8U8xJsOiHQ",
        range: "Dashboard",
    })
console.log(response.data)
```

i am geting this response

```
data: {
          error: {
            code: 400,
            message: 'Unable to parse range: Dashboard',
            errors: [
              {
                message: 'Unable to parse range: Dashboard',
                domain: 'global',
                reason: 'badRequest'
              }
            ],
            status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'
          }
        },
```

i am geting this error , i am passing everything correctly but still facing the issue

[spreadsheet range image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qEUw.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: please check, i have updated it

Comment: 'Dashboard' is sheet name not range.

Comment: It seems you're using the Google Sheets API. I've updated the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`Dashboard` is the name of a sheet within your Spreadsheet with the given Spreadsheet ID, it is **NOT** a range.
Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=en#cell) on what's actually a range and a how to format a valid range.

If you were to read cell `A1` to `D3` in your sheet `Dashboard` you should use `Dashboard!A1:D3` as a parameter value for `range`.

```js
const { sheets } = await authentication()

const response =
    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId:
            "13BMKBHCQ94tgv9koMkzH1bvgPZhaz0yZW8U8xJsOiHQ",
        range: "Dashboard!A1:D3",
    })
console.log(response.data)
```

From your code I'm assuming you use the `googleapi` JavaScript client library from Google. You can have a look at the [documentation for `get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sheets/classes/Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.html#get) there as well, which shows examples of expected values for parameters.

Comment: i have created a new google sheet i am getting values from that. also the id which it has created is different from the earlier   ,                                                                                             old id = 13BMKBHCQ94tgv9koMkzH1bvgPZhaz0yZW8U8xJsOiHQ                                                                new id = 1dCmLqDvprVfldCmBumBz6WCokNYXTRwm_nwiNQ3514w

Comment: Not sure, what's the problem. Just use the ID of the Spreadsheet you need to access.